# GET Save file from AS/400 via FTP Empty File

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

Im trying to download SAVEFILE of a library from AS/400 server.
always I get an empty file which is 0 byte,

these are the steps I followed

```
    Go to a MS-DOS Shell.
Go to the location on the PC where you want to store the save file.
Type:

FTP (AS/400_IP_ADDRESS)

Or

FTP (AS/400 _NAME)
Enter your AS/400 username and password for that system when prompted.
To ensure the transfer mode is binary (there will be no conversion), type:

BIN
To go to the library on the AS/400 where the save file is stored, type:

CD LIBRARY
To transfer the save file from the AS/400 to your PC, type:

GET NAME
When the transfer is complete, exit the ftp session by typing:

QUIT
To close the MS-DOS shell, type:

EXIT
```

in as400 side I can see file size is 24576 bytes

FTP prompt return "226 File transfer completed successfully."

but file is empty.

any reason ?

Comment: Exactly what steps do you perform?

Answer (score 0):

We always create the empty savf first.

In FTP, go into BINARY mode.
CD and LCD, to change the remote & local current directory, if desired.
Change NAMFMT, if desired.

If you did not change the local directory, perhaps the file went someplace else, where you are not looking.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the library list on your FTP GET, specify the library the save file is in.  For instance, if you did a `SAVLIB ... SAVF(TESTLIB/MYSAVF)` then on the FTP GET command, specify `GET TESTLIB/MYSAVF`.  If this does not help, update your question to show the exact steps you used to create the save file and to FTP it off.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to:

ftp ipaddress

bin

get LIBARY/SAVF SAVF(this just tells it to drop the file in tmp with the same name)

quit